# Inserting row from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, msdtc, distributed-transactions

I have set up a linked server with the MSDASQL provider in MSSQL to connect to a MySQL instance. I have installed and configured the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver connector.  Everything seems to work fine to query data from the MySQL instance, but inserting or updating any data is not working.  The following command:

```
INSERT OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT id FROM test')
values (1)
```

intended on inserting a simple value of 1 returns the error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.21]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1  The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".

I have also attempted to open an editable results pane for the MySql test table and insert data that way, I receive the following error:

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
>
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Optional feature not supported".

Does anyone have some insight or experience on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordination) service running on one or both machines (assuming MySQL server is windows also)?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that the service is running.